# Pandas to_csv, file readable only with LibreOffice

Tags: python, excel, pandas, csv, compression

I'm doing default Pandas read_excel, performing some actions on the dataframe, and at the end I'm saving the file:

```
df.to_csv(target, index=False, compression='gzip', sep='|')
```

although the file is readable only with LibreOffice Calc -UTF-8, USA.
If file is opened with Excel then I can see the filename in the first row / first column, and bunch of diamons with question marks in the other fields. Tried to set encoding in 'to_csv' for 'utf-8', 'utf-8-sig', 'utf-16' but nothing seems to work.
How to make this file readable in Excel also?

Thanks!

Comment: You probably need to uncompress the file first, it may not be able to decode gzip.

Comment: Or just get rid of the `compression` option when creating the CSV.

Answer (score 0):

Compression was the issue here. Thanks!